# How do I write a macro that has the functionality as Mark Entry button of the References tab in Word Ribbon bar

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I need to create **a ribbon bar button** which will work as a **shortcut** for the **Mark Entry button of the Index group on the References tab**. I searched for ways to do this. But I was unable to find any macro which will do this.

This can be done by adding the ribbon bar button in the xml using the following code.

```
<button idMso="IndexMarkEntry" label="Index entry" />
```

But I need to put another image as the button icon image. If I use the idmso, I cant use the icon image I want. 
So I need to find another way to add this button. I have to write a vb custom routine to replace Mark Entry, but I don't know what to write. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you need a macro to do this? You can do it from File | Options | Customize Ribbon.

Comment: My ribbon bar button is in a tab which is created by myself. I tried to do as you said in the comment. I went to 'Customize Ribbon'  and under customized the ribbon (All tabs), I am unable to find my tab. How can I find my tab there?

Comment: How did you create your tab?

Comment: I am using a .dotm file.

Comment: I see that since my original comment you have changed your question to 'how do I use a different icon'. The simple answer to that is that you can't, unless you write a custom routine to replace Mark Entry. Built-in commands can only use their built-in icons.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can't change the icon if I use the idMso. I am asking for help to write a custom routine. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite your question to ask for the help you actually need, which seems to be "how do I write a macro that marks something as an index entry".

Comment: Got it, I'll change my question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the functionality to work as a shortcut for the 'Mark Entry button of the Index group on the References tab' and added the custom image as icon to the ribbon bar button (Index entry) that I have created.

Open the .dotm file in Custom UI editor and add the custom image icon to the customUI.xml.

This should be added in the customUI.xml :

```
<button id="IndexEntry" size = "normal" label="Index entry" onAction="Ribbon.TPS_IndexEntry" image="Index-entry_16" screentip="Mark Entry (Alt+Shift+X)" supertip="Add the selected text to the index" keytip="IE" />
```

Open the .dotm and open the developer view of the template.
Insert this under Ribbon :

```
Public Sub TPS_IndexEntry(ByVal Control As IRibbonControl)
Word.Application.Run "TPS_IndexEntry"
End Sub
```

Then insert this under Macros :

```
Public Sub TPS_IndexEntry()
Dialogs(wdDialogMarkIndexEntry).Show
End Sub
```

This will generate  a ribbon bar button which will work as a short cut to the Mark Entry button.